# Find same records for each id

Tags: mysql

I have this problem
I have to find all records with same ProductID

example

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021cd/5

The results are wrong
i need to get all phID that have all products

the phID 1002 does not have the ProductID 8,9 and 14 so cant be there

if i enter (8,9,12,14,25) the results must be 1001,1004 because 1001 have (8,9,12,14,25) and 1004 the same
but if i enter (12,25,49) the results must be 1001,1002,1004 because all have (12,25,49)

any help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query gets the phIDs that have *any* of the products listed, not *all* of them. Try these:

```
SELECT phID, count(*) c
FROM Tablename
WHERE ProductID in (8,9,12,14,25)
GROUP BY phID
HAVING c = 5;

SELECT phID, count(*) c
FROM Tablename
WHERE ProductID in (12,25,49)
GROUP BY phID
HAVING c = 3;
```